# How to find the length of the longest consecutive repetition of a certain repeating word in a string?

Tags: python, repeat

I'm trying to write a function that identifies how many times a certain word is repeated in its longest consecutive repetition.

I want the below function to print "5" because the word "hi" repeats 5 times in its most repetitive sequence inside of the string. How can I accomplish this?

```
    import re
    string = 'hihihihihibyebyebyehihihihibyebyebyehihi'
    print(len(max(re.compile("(hi+hi)*").findall(string))))
```

Output: 4

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can use:

```
max(map(len, re.findall('(?:hi)+', string)))//len('hi')
```

Output: `5`

Alternative, if you have a potentially variable length of the match. Capture but the unit chunk and the total match with repeats:

```
string = 'hxihxihxihxihxibyebyebyehihihihibyebyebyehihi'

max(len(a)//len(b) for a,b in re.findall('((hx?i)+)', string))
# 5
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend starting with the regex part. It probably isn't doing what you think it's doing.

Out of curiosity, I ran just a portion of the last line:

```py
re.compile("(hi+hi)*").findall(string)
```

and the result was:

```py
['hihi', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'hihi', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'hihi', '']
```

I can now see why the output was 4: the longest string in this list is 4 characters long.

This unexpected result brings up a few questions:

1. What patterns is the regex `"(hi+hi)*"` actually matching, and why?
2. What do all those empty strings mean?
3. The longest match was `"hihi"` which is only 2 `hi`'s, but the output was 4. Why?

Try taking a closer look at the documentation for regex, I think you'll find that the expression you are looking for is `"(?:hi)+"` which roughly means ~at least one repetition of "hi"~